# Sample DockerFile for playwright test

Tags: dockerfile, playwright

trying to dockerize my playwright test and having looking for some reference on how i can write the dockerfile. Did some searches but could not find much help. Could anyone share a sample that i can refer.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your Dockerfile you can put:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal
```

followed by the code that executes your tests.

Check the [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/docker) here for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste Dockerfile for those who have no idea how to use docker, [source](https://medium.com/geekculture/e2e-testing-with-playwright-and-docker-91dd7eb11793)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal

# copy project (including tests)
COPY . /e2e

WORKDIR /e2e

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install
# Install browsers
RUN npx playwright install

# Run playwright test
CMD [ "npx", "playwright", "test", "--reporter=list" ]
```

Comment: I'm surprised installing playwright is required if I'm using the playwright image. Is that correct?

Comment: Good question, when I was testing today, I did not need to have `RUN npx playwright install` in the Dockerfile. The browsers were provided by the playwright image. (I was testing with `mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.35.1-jammy`

Answer (score 0):

I do think the [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/docker) should have an actual Dockerfile example. Just saying "use the Playwright image" does not provide enough to get a working image.

This is what I came up with for a project after creating it with [the `npm init playwright@latest` command](https://playwright.dev/docs/intro#installing-playwright).

**NOTE:** The version of the playwright NPM package should match the Docker tag. So, this assumes I am using playwright 1.38.1 NPM package to match the `v1.38.1-jammy` image tag.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.38.1-jammy

RUN npm install -g npm@10.1.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm i

# Copy the rest of the files into the image.
COPY . .

CMD npx playwright --version
```